# Fillcolor in Dataframe an convert it from Julia to Excel

Tags: julia, xlsx

I would like to set a fillcolor for a specific cell in Excel when transfering it from a Julia Dataframe to Excel file. Please help.

Right now I have used this example but how do I e.g. set the cell where "First" is presented to an RGB color?

```
using DataFrames
using XLSX

df1 = DataFrames.DataFrame(COL1=[10,20,30], COL2=["First", "Sec", "Third"])

XLSX.writetable("report.xlsx", REPORT_A=(collect(DataFrames.eachcol(df1)), DataFrames.names(df1)))
```

Comment: This does not seem to be supported by the library in a proper way (yet). See: https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl/issues/63